# Elasticsearch - query for keyword value

Tags: elasticsearch

ES 7.8, mapping:

```
    "id": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 300
        },
        "lower_case_sort": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 10,
          "normalizer": "case_insensitive_sort"
        }
      }
    }
```

How can I search my index and get `id.keyword` and `id.lower_case_sort` values? All I can get is `id` value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the actual terms that have been indexed in sub-fields using [`docvalue_fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/run-a-search.html#docvalue-fields) (only works for non-text fields).

For instance, if you index this

```
POST test/_doc
{
  "id": "ONE two"
}
```

You can retrieve the actual doc values using:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "docvalue_fields": ["id.keyword", "id.lower_case_sort"]
}
```

And you'll get this:

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "bZ3NenMBfUaK6xUNT7vB",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "id" : "ONE two"
    },
    "fields" : {
      "id.lower_case_sort" : [
        "one two"
      ],
      "id.keyword" : [
        "ONE two"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

As you can see, you get

- the original value in `_source.id`
- the indexed doc values for each sub-field in `fields.id.keyword` and `fields.id.lower_case_sort`

Comment: `only works for non-text fields` ? ah ok, keyword is not text

Comment: What I meant was only on fields that are not of type `text`